# Importing DBF files into Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, xml, dbf

I'm working through the book "GIS Tutorial 1" and it wants me to open up a DBF file in Microsoft Excel. But when I try to open it, I'm running into some issues. First thing that seems weird is although the extension is .dbf, it's listed as an XML document.
[image]

When I try to open it up in Excel, instead of getting the neat table I expected I got a bunch of additional information.

[image]

I opened up the file as listed as 'OpenOffice.org ...' and it mostly gave me what I wanted, but some of the text is left as ####.

[image]

How can I get a neat table like in picture 3, but using a DBF file? Also how can I get it to include all data, and not block some out with #####?

Comment: You don't say what version of Excel you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ### are a way for openoffice to tell you that your column is too narrow for the data it contains. If you adjust it, you should start seeing your data.

Therefore, if you open your dbf file with openoffice, adjust the width of the columns (a double click on the separations between the headers should automatically adjust it to your data) and paste it in excel, you should be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Open a new excel worksheet and drag and drop the DBF file from the window explorer to the excel worksheet. It should work fine.